# Wordpress loop within loop error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

On my parent page, i have a custom page template calling another template:

```
if( have_posts() ): while( have_posts() ): the_post(); ?>

<div class="wrapper">


<?php get_template_part( 'template', 'page-section' ); ?>

<?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Inside template-page-section.php, I have the following:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Page Section
*/
$args = array(
    'post_parent' => 9,
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'orderby' => 'menu_order',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'order' => 'ASC'
);

$wpq = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>

<?php while ( $wpq->have_posts() ) : $wpq->the_post(); ?>

<?php if ( $post->ID == 101 ) {
    include( 'template-slider.php' );
} ?> 

<div class="page-section">
    <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
    <?php /* The loop */ ?>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
</div>

<?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata();?>
```

Within the template-slider.php, is the following:

```
<div id="slider-container">
    <ul id="slider">
        <? $query = get_pages( 
            array(
                'post_type' => 'slides',
                'orderby' => 'menu_order',
                'posts_per_page' => -1
            ));


            foreach( $query as $post ) { 
            setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
            <?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail', $thumbsize[0] ); ?>

            <li>
            <img src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>">
            </li>
            <?php } wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

        </ul>   
    </div>
```

The issue is that once wordpress hits the loop within the slider-template, the information that it echos for the post content is not a child post of the parent, but the parents content.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I cant figure it out!

Comment: In the `template-slider.php` file, you do not need to include the `setup_postdata( $post );` line as `get_pages()` will include the post ID in the array. Also, you may want to rename `$post` as it is a global WP uses; not sure if it's any issue here, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just an untested guess, but try the following:

**template-page-section.php**

```
$wpq = get_posts( $args );
if( $wpq ) {
    foreach( $wpq as $p )
    {
        if ( $p->ID == 101 ) {
            include( 'template-slider.php' );
        }
        ?>
            <div class="page-section">
                <h1><?php echo $p->post_title; ?></h1>
                <?php echo $p->post_content; ?>
            </div>
        <?php
    }
}
```

**template-slider.php**

```
<div id="slider-container">
    <ul id="slider">
        <?php 
        $query_pages = get_pages( 
            array(
                'post_type' => 'slides',
                'orderby' => 'menu_order',
                'posts_per_page' => -1
        ));
        if( $query_pages )
        {
            foreach( $query_pages as $pg ) { 
                $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $pg->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail', $thumbsize[0] ); ?>
                <li>
                <img src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>">
                </li><?php 
            } 
        } ?>
    </ul>   
</div>
```

Reference: [**When should you use WP_Query vs query_posts() vs get_posts()?**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/1753/12615)

Comment: Thanks so much @brasofilo! Also I appreciate the link to explain your answer!

Comment: Well, simply dumping a correct code doesn't make a good answer, really glad it worked at prime-time :)